# Finding $\inf(\{30, 40\})$ and $\sup(\{2, 5\})$ in Hasse diagram

Tags: relations, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

[image]

I would like to ask what is $\inf(\{30, 40\})$ and $\sup(\{2, 5\})$. I think that $\sup(\{2, 5\})$ is $20$ and $\inf(\{30, 40\})$ does not exist, but it may be $2$, but $5$ is on the same level and I don't know if I should consider the length of path to the node or not.

Comment: neither of them exist. It's not a lattice so they don't exist for some pairs. You found pairs that witness the fact that the poset is not a lattice.

Comment: You claim that $\sup\{2,5\}=20$, but notice that the upper bounds of $\{2,5\}$ are $\{20,30,40,120\}$, and none of them is a least one. So there is no *least upper bound*, which would be the supremum.

Comment: The length of the path between nodes is meaningless for determination of suprema and infima.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, hence in my first comment I wrote "they (referring to infimum and supremum) don't exist for some pairs". If they did to all pairs, then it would be a lattice.

Comment: @amrsa Ok thank you, but why ist 20 not least upper bound? Would 20 have to be in relation with 30 if it was supremum?

Comment: @MajerníkTomáš Given that the set of common upper bounds of $2$ and $5$ are $20,30,40,120$, the *least upper bound* is the least of these. But this set has two minimal elements: $20$ and $30$, that is, $20\nleq30$ and $30\nleq20$, but both of them are less than $40$ or $120$.

Comment: @amrsa Sorry.. read too fast, deleting comment.

Answer (score 2):

The diagram has a bottom element, in this case $1$ and a top element, $120$.
When this happens, every pair has a supremum if and only if every pair has a infimum.

The supremum of $2$ and $5$ does not exist because among their upper bounds there is not a least one, so there is not the infimum of $20$ and $30$, which are their minimal upper bounds.

Notice that if you delete one of the three lines: $2$-$20$, $2$-$30$, $5$-$20$, you obtain a lattice.